# Deleting and appending list from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I would like to delete a list and append the fore-end and back-end list and generate a new list.  I have the following two structures:

```
typedef struct term {
   SYMBOL symbol;
   union {
       LIST termlist;
       struct term* term;
   } super;
   LIST   args;
   NAT    stamp;
   NAT    size;
} *TERM, TERM_NODE;

typedef struct LIST_HELP {
   struct LIST_HELP *cdr;
   POINTER           car;
} LIST_NODE;

typedef LIST_NODE *LIST;
```

Using these two structure I have a TERM like:

```
forall([X8,X9],implies(connected(X8,X9),exists([V],and(or(equal(h_1(X8),U),equal(h_2(X8),U)),connected(U,X9)))
```

Here all are symbols. Suppose if  `forall`  is a symbol then the rest act as the arguments for `forall`.  It is a kind of `Term` composed of another `Term`.  I would like to remove `[V]` from this and append the list before and after of it.  Can you please tell me how I would do that?

Comment: in your `term` struct, where is `LIST` defined? Where is `POINTER` defined in the `LIST_HELP` struct?

Comment: LIST_HELP is a linked list. In the term, args are list.It is defined as LIST args.So a term is constructed as a symbol and its arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably homework; so, lets say you have a list `LIST l1`, you find it's cdr by `l1->cdr`. Now: To delete one entry from the list what you want to do is set the cdr's cdr as the current's cdr like so:

```
l1->cdr = (l1->cdr)->cdr;
```

You effectively deleted the entry that was previously in `l1->cdr`. What you also have to do is remember that previous value of `l1->cdr` so you can free the memory used by it.